# Interrupt a program process running from class A to class B of another class

Tags: python, windows, multithreading, class, tkinter

```
import os
import sys
import time
import tkinter as tk


class Time:
    def __init__(self):
        self.Time_sleep()
        self.Num_calc()

    def Time_sleep(self):
        time.sleep(100)  # Standby for 100 seconds

    def Num_calc(self):
        for i in range(250000000):  # Approximately 5 seconds processing time
            pass


class GUI:
    def __init__(self):  # Creation of blueprints
        self.count = 3

        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.geometry("1400x200")
        self.integer_variable = tk.BooleanVar()
        self.label = tk.Label(self.root, text="")
        self.label.pack()
        self.button = tk.Button(self.root, text="interruption", command=self.end)
        self.button.pack()
        self.label.after(1, lambda: self.countdown(self.count, self.processing, True))

    def countdown(self, remaining, callback, coll):
        if coll == False:
            puo = "\nProcess is complete."
            pip = "Closes"

            self.button.pack_forget()
        else:
            puo = "Execute the process"
            pip = "Starts"

        if remaining <= 0:
            callback()
        else:
            self.root.title("Backup")
            self.label.configure(
                text="{}：{} after {} second".format(puo, pip,remaining), font=("Helvetica", 20)
            )
            self.root.after(1000, lambda: self.countdown(remaining - 1, callback, coll))

    def processing(self):
        self.label.configure(text="Processing", font=("Helvetica", 20))
        self.root.update_idletasks()

        Time_arg = Time()

        self.countdown(5, self.end_taken, False)

    def end(self):
        self.integer_variable.set(False)
        self.root.destroy()

    def end_taken(self):
        self.integer_variable.set(True)
        self.root.destroy()


class Interruption:
    def __init__(self, app):
        if app == False:
            self.root = tk.Tk()
            self.label = tk.Label(
                self.root,
                text="Processing has been interrupted.",
                font=("Helvetica", 20),
            ).pack()
            self.button = tk.Button(
                self.root, text="Quit", command=self.root.destroy
            ).pack()
        else:
            self.root = tk.Tk()
            self.root.destroy()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    GUI = GUI()
    GUI.root.mainloop()
    num = GUI.integer_variable.get()
    Interruption(num).root.mainloop()
```

＜ Overview of the attached program & what we want to do ＞

1: Display the countdown to execute the process "Abort button → class Interruption() will show the information text after the interruption".

2: Execution of the process of the class Time "Suspend button → class Interruption() will show a guideline sentence after the interruption".

3: Display of countdown to close the screen after the process is finished

4: End of all processes

＜＜＜【Reason and purpose of question】＞＞＞

In def processing of class GUI, the suspend button is displayed. In def processing, two functions invoked from class Time(), which is another class, are processed, but I would like to interrupt these processes by pressing the interrupt button at any timing during processing.

＜If the processing of def Time_sleep is 1 day, the processing we want to do is as follows＞

× 　"suspend button → suspend after processing def Time_sleep: because it makes no sense to suspend a long process after it is finished."

○　"suspend button → suspend during the processing of def Time_sleep, and terminate the processing of Time_arg = Time() itself and execute the next processing".

:<Problems with the attached program>

(1): At the time of def processing, the suspend button cannot be pressed in the first place.

(2)： Problem 1): If class Time() is executed in a separate thread using the threading function, the suspend button can be pressed. However, only the process on the class GUI terminates successfully, and the functions of class Time(), which is a separate thread, are processed without interruption.

＜Research and Tested＞

Creation and execution of a separate threading using the thread function
　→ Problem 2

Referenced URL:

・https://www.pythontutorial.net/python-concurrency/python-stop-thread/

→ URL that I thought might be a clue to solving the problem, but an error occurred and it was not possible to execute.

・https://tsudango-tech.com/88/

・https://teratail.com/questions/76909

・https://magazine.techacademy.jp/magazine/22815

・https://www.pythontutorial.net/python-concurrency/python-stop-thread/

・https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/threading.html%5C>

・https://magazine.techacademy.jp/magazine/22221

＜Additional information＞

・I am still in the process of learning programming, so I am not well versed in some areas, but I would appreciate any suggestions you may have for the future.

・I am still learning how to program, so I am not well versed in this area, but I would appreciate any suggestions you may have for the future.

・If this problem is not solved, we will process everything in the same class, which is something we did not want to do for various reasons.

・Most of this program was created using Bing's ChatGPT. I have corrected inappropriate parts and bugs to the best of my ability and coded the program as shown in the attached program.

Environment.

Anaconda3, Windows 11, jupyter notebook 6.5.4, python 3.10.9

Comment: One `tk.Tk()` and `mainloop()` can do main script entirely. .But  why are you using duplicates?

Comment: By separating the classes, I was able to get closer to what I wanted to do, so I have kept them separate and modified the program.
Eventually, I would like to improve my coding skills so that I can integrate class GUI and class Interruption so that I can code the GUI process and the class Time execution process separately.